# padrão MVC para Controller no codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, api, mvc

Tenho o seguinte cenário, alguns models que serão acessados via administração (site) e via cliente (app), na administração ele poderá ler e escrever dados e no cliente apenas ler dados.

Minha dúvida, qual é a melhor forma seguindo o padrão MVC para otimizar código (não repetir)?

Uma vez que a administração e cliente vão consumir dados, sendo a única diferença que um vai consumir em html e o outro json.

Pensei em fazer um controller contendo todo a comunicação com os models e mais um controller para cada finalidade (administração e model), esses acessariam o controller principal.

Esse meu pensamento está correto?

Comment: A resposta básica seria: "Entender o básico do MVC + experiencia"... Cada projeto é de uma maneira, realmente acho que tem frameworks um pouco melhores que CI. Creio que a pergunta seja muito ampla

Comment: Já viu HMVC? Pode ser que resolva para o seu caso.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz achei essa ideia interessante, não conhecia esse modelo

Comment: então, da uma olhada aqui, caso ainda não tenha achado né https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danilo, aconselho você a adicionar uma camada intermediária para receber as regras de negócio. Ela ficaria entre o **Controller** e o **Model**, normalmente essa camada é chamada de **Service**. Pois assim a replicação do código pode ser até zero. 
Além de um **Controller** para cada via de comunicação. Pois um poder fazer o render da tela é o outro retorna formato json ou qualquer outro.

Comment: Erra isso mesmo que eu estava querendo, já estava até pensando em usar um framework só para api, no caso o lumen